# Is calculus still being developed?

Tags: calculus, analysis, soft-question

I have heard a podcast episode about calculus, with a mathematician and a journalist, on which he asked the mathematician if there still were developments being made in calculus. He answered that no, but that there were in (real) analysis. Which made me even more sense since that *advanced calculus* refers to (real) analysis, that *real analysis* is a famous next-step after calculus, and that some advanced cool stuff I have seen were said to be of analysis.

So, is calculus ***basically*** (emphasis on ***basically***) what is learnt in calc1–calc3, being more of it real analysis? Could you, like, say that you learn**t** calculus?

P.S.: I am not a mathematician, nor am I in any college. I also do not know if this type of question is allowed — pardon me if it be not.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think Calculus I - III are more of a "tour" through some of the basic concepts in the field of analysis, and in particular the ones most friendly towards applications. Analysis in general is so, so so **SO** much broader than that, and involves a much higher level of rigor. ("Infinitesimal changes?" "Instantaneous rates of change?" "Area under a curve?" How do you define these? How might you generalize these - beyond just a few dimensions, or to different underlying objects (like $p$-adic numbers or matrices or whatever else)?) [cont.]

Comment: There are subfields that explore all of these, of course: the basics being real, complex, and $p$-adic analysis; measure theory; functional analysis; and more.

In that viewpoint, the answer is pretty self-explanatory: it is very, very much still in development and very much still having discoveries on a regular basis. What an introductory college student learns will probably stay the same for a good while of course, but the deeper you go, there is always a lot more people have thought about and discovered -- and a LOT more they've yet to. [cont.]

Comment: Granted this is a somewhat subjective matter; this is mainly my thoughts on the matter, and as someone who hasn't even finished grad school, I more than welcome the thoughts of others less naive than myself.

Comment: Can you please let us know where can I find mathematical podcasts?

Comment: @DarshanP. the one mentioned by the OP is the Numberphile podcast of Steven Strogatz (if I'm not wrong). Numberphile and also 3 Blue 1 Brown has got some excellent "mathematical podcasts".

Comment: I can understand the appeal and, for someone still fairly early in mathematical studies, the naturalness of this question, but for what it's worth to me it's a bit like asking if there are still developments being made in the application of wheels and other curved objects to labor-saving devices.

Comment: @SayanDutta although your whatsapp status says "You are not supposed to understand this" I understood the podcast source thanks +3b1b & Numpherphile are one of my fvrt YT channels.

Comment: @DarshanP. Bruh....